# How to Create custom Tab in php?

Tags: tab

How Can I create a custom tab using SFDC PHP Tool kit ?

I need to create a custom tab for a custom object. Can any one help, which class should be instantiated for custom tab ?

Can any one show a sample custom tab creation code in php ?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_tab.htm - Gives you details around the CustomTab Object and https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Create_Delete_Undelete_Sample_(Enterprise) - Provides information on create call in PHP toolkit. 
 I think combining both should resolve your issue.

Comment: I have checked in PHP-Toolkit there is no option to make a call for create custom tab.Can you suggest method defined in PHP Toolkit to create custom tab ?